# What were the slaves doing on the spaceship?

Tags: alien-nation

From the intro to the 1989 *Alien Nation* TV show:

> That was the scene in California's Mohabi desert five years ago. Our historic first view of the newcomer ship. Theirs was a slave ship, carrying a quarter of a million beings, bred to adapt and labour in any environment. But they've washed ashore on Earth, with no way to get back to where they came from. And in the last five years the Newcomers have become the latest addition to the population of Los Angeles.

I've watched the whole series but didn't manage to catch an explanation of what the slaves were actually doing aboard the spaceship before it crashed. The Overseers were obviously controlling the Newcomers to extract some sort of forced labour from them (they're slaves, after all). However, what specifically were the Newcomers doing during their enslavement?

Comment: This isn't really the first Alien Nation question, is it?

Comment: @Z.Cochrane Looks like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ship Gruza appears to be a transport, taking slaves from a place that they're no longer needed to a place where they're needed more. Although the Tenctonese seem to form a general underclass, at least some were used as slave labour for **mining**

> This tracking device is very much like what **the overseers used on us at mining camps.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien Nation: Partners](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0508900/)</sup></sub>

On board the ship itself, most of the aliens seem to have been in hibernation with a skeleton crew of a few hundred kept awake to run and service the ship and its crew.

> **CAL-TECH PROFESSOR:**   *From the time mankind first gazed up   at the stars there had been     speculation about a visit by people     from
>   "out there."  How ironic that     when that first contact was made,   the
>   two hundred and sixty thousand    occupants aboard the craft were as
>     surprised as we were about their    arrival.  That they awakened from
>     **frozen hibernation** to find their    malfunctioning autopilot had landed
>     them here by mistake.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien Nation: Script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Alien_Nation_Bannon_Cameron_October_1987.html)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 5):

It is a major plot point in the original *[Alien Nation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094631/)* film that the conditions of the Newcomers previous slavery were a secret.  Primarily, this was to conceal the fact that they could be controlled by the drug Jabroka.  However, it would have been difficult to provide the Earth authorities with any detailed rundown of how the slavery system worked without mentioning the drug.  It is never clear precisely how the Newcomer leaders managed it, but they did manage to keep the details of their enslavement a secret.

Comment: Could you include a quote or two to back this up please? I watched the TV series but haven't managed to watch the film yet.

Comment: @TheDarkLord I'll try to find the clip later; at the moment I have to go proctor a final exam in *real* science.

Comment: OK, good luck on both fronts.